# How to correctly reference posted form data in Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I think the reason my beforeSend function is not working (No background color change) is because it doesn't see the value of the variable id. How does one correctly correctly reference the id variable posted from the form. Here's the relevant html and js:

html

```
<div id="rec<?php echo $id; ?>"class="del_box">
 <form method="post" class="delform">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
  <input name="ad_link" type="hidden" id="ad_link" value="<?php echo $ad_link; ?>" />
  <input name="listing_img" type="hidden" id="listing_img" value="<?php echo $listing_img; ?>" />
  <button type="submit">Delete</button>
 </form>
</div>
```

js

```
   $("document").ready(function() {
$(".delform").submit(function() {
    data = $(this).serialize();
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "delete_list.php",
            data: data,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#" + "rec" + data["id"]).animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'
                }, 600);
            }
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $("#rec" + response.idc).slideUp(600, function() {
                        $("#rec" + response.idc).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("An error has ocurred: sentence: " + response.sentence + "error: " + response.error);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("An Error has ocurred contacting with the server. Sorry");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
});
```

CSS

```
.del_box {
background-image: none;
background-color:#9F9F9F;
}
```

Comment: First, you need the [jquery-color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) to animate colours. Have you got it? Second, `data` is a string so you can't use `data["id"]`. Try something like `$('#rec' + this.elements.id.value)`.

Comment: Couple things: first, that trailing comma on line 14 will cause problems on some IE versions, second set a breakpoint in the javascript console and make sure your jquery selector is actually selecting something valid (e.g. that 'id' is the value you want), third (and most importantly) `beforeSend` is generally for doing things like adding custom headers to your http request, it seems completely unnecessary here. Just move it to the top of your submit handler.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm getting a syntax error in dreamweaver if i drop that comma

Comment: @Phil I didn't know about the color plugin, thank you. But I don't think it's needed in this instance??

Comment: Ah, you posted the rest of your code. Yes, you need that comma. You didn't have the success and error handlers posted originally. When enumerating object properties, if you have an extra comma like so `var foo = {foo:'bar', baz:'fez',};` (note the comma after 'fez') it is ignored by most browsers but not old versions of IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do what I think you are trying to do, then the `beforeSend` is not necessary. You are animating an object, but that does not necessarily need to be tied to the Ajax request. Just do the animation outside the request. Like so:

```
data = $(this).serialize();   
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this listing?")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "delete_list.php",
            data: data,   
        });
        $("#rec" + data["id"]).animate({'backgroundColor': '#fb6c6c'}, 600);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying it now. So I have a success function after the before send so I'm wondering about the timing sequence for that. I will post my entire js and try what you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you separating # from rec?

```
$("#" + "rec" + data["id"])
```

You can also write something like this:

```
$("#rec" + data["id"])
```

Anyway Ramsay Smith's answer is right!